# Define a standard deviation metric based on other metrics

Tags: kibana

I have some data in the following format:

```
{
  timestamp: Date;
  a: number;
  b: number;
}
```

I'm able to create a metric `sum(a)`, another metric `sum(b)`, how to define the third metric `std_deviation(sum(a)/sum(b))` in the Kibana webpage?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out [Kibana doesn't support Bucket script](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/4707), so it is not possible to define a metric based on other metrics.